# null pointer exception in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-7

i was trying some code and i got the NullPointerException.
Code snippet is as:

```
            String dialogmessage = "Welcome - " +user;
            int dialogtype = JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE;
            dialogtype = JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE;
            String dialogs = null;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component)null, dialogmessage, dialogs,                     dialogtype);
            usrname.setText("");
            pswrd.setText("");
            frame.setVisible(false);
```

please help me out

Comment: how have you tried debugging this? [ask]

Comment: You should show the detailed error at console here. So your problem more obvious.

Comment: Check-out the line number indicated on the first line after the NullPointeException message. On that line, check everything that is before a dot ('.'), one of them is `null`, hence the NPE (auto-unboxing may also throw NPE).

Answer (score 1):

Although I completely agree @djechlin comment, I still don't have enough reputation to downvote, so...

**FIRST** - StackOverflow is not the place to ask for your homework to be solved by others, and less even without investigating or putting a little bit of effort.

**SECOND** - NullPointerException, as other exceptions, provides the line where it's thrown at, so it uses to be fairly easy to fix. You say nothing about this, no fix. My bet? Either usrname, pswrd or frame variables haven't been assigned. Realize that this is declaring:

```
JFrame frame;
```

And this is assigning:

```
frame = new JFrame();
```

If you only declare and then try to use the variable, since it's internally initialized to null, what you're telling to the machine is:

```
do null.someStuff()
```

And there you've got your exception.

**EDIT:** I'd also like to mention that exceptions, as far as I know (or at least NullPointerException), are not IDE-dependent (i.e. you get NullPointer in NetBeans, you'll get so in eclipse as well).

Answer (score 0):

-Are you setting the variable "user" on the first line?

-you are setting the String "dialogs" to null, (that would be the title), suggest checking the api here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

suggest setting string dialogs to "title" and see if that fixes the problem...

Comment: basically anything can be null here, only need is to check the stack trace.